# Adding integers

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and android programming.Can someone explain to me what is wrong here? 
When i run it it gives me the errors:

> Error:illegal start of expression, Error: identifier expected, Error:
>   not a statement, Error: ';' expected, Error: ')' expected,
>   Error:illegal start of type, Error:reached end of file while parsing.

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Button
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


    //EditText
    EditText nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    cob.getText().toString();
    nop.getText().toString();

    public void total = cob+ nop;

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        tv.setText(final.total)
        })

        //TextView
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
}}
```

Comment: put a semi colon here   tv.setText(final.total)

Comment: Threre's at least half a dozen issues in this code.

Comment: You can´t use access modifier inside a method, since theyr scope is just inside the method

Comment: Learn Java and try to understand the error by yourself. Will help you great in future. Don't believe in copy-paste. Too many issue in this code. Fixing one would point another.

Comment: as suggested it is a very good practice to try to solve your errors and the ask for a more specif one, keep coding

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        tv.setText(final.total)
        })
```

Should be immediately followed by an ';', same goes for the setText call.

An error like that always means you forgot one of those, or misplaced/forgotten some brackets, ...

Since you don't state the exact error message: I'm just guessing it's this error, but it's possible there are more in your code.

EDIT:

And, as others already mentioned: `public void total = cob+ nop;` makes no sense at all. void is not a valid datatype in Java, so you can't declare a 'void'.

Answer (score 0):

The second button click event is not right.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    tv.setText(final.total);
        }
    });
```

`total` is also wrong.

It should be

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(cob.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(nob.getText().toString()) ;
```

---

Putting all these together

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //EditText
    EditText nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(cob.getText().toString());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(nop.getText().toString());

    public void total = a + b;

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText(total);
        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int total = Integer.parseInt(cob.getText().toString())+ Integer.parseInt( nop.getText().toString());

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    });
```

remove

```
cob.getText().toString();
nop.getText().toString();

public void total = cob+ nop;
```